# C#, What type of database should I use for chat user profiles?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio, chatbot

I want to make user profiles based off of the users activity in my chat box, for example what kinds of commands they use, and keep track of how often they are used, or how many times a string is typed. Does anyone know?

Another example; says, John: "!command", then my bot will keep track of who used the command and how many times, so my bot can tell which commands are used the most and by which users. Thanks

Sorry no code to post, I'm just working out the concept and not sure where to start. I have the chatbot up and running, reading and able to write to chat, I'm just looking to increase what it can do. I'm new to C# and really new to bots and databases.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really up to you. If you want to persist data locally you can write your own files in xml or json, or use a no-sql db like mongo or others.

If you want your data stored in a relational db, then you have Sql server, oracle etc... pick one.

If you want to store you data on Amazon to have it ready in the cloud then you have a bunch of options from RDS to your own EC2 instance.

Your needs seem really simple, I would suggest just storing the file as a local JSON file unless you need a server to do something with it.

If you just want to store data locally on the users machine and then read it back at a later date take a look at one of my projects on GitHub: https://github.com/kelias/Jarloo.Sojurn/blob/master/Jarloo.Sojurn/Data/LocalJsonPersistenceManager.cs

That class will read and write JSON data to/from the disk.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to store data about the users who visit my chat, and then be able to use it to interact with them better, so maybe like you said, local JSON. Like I said though, I'm new to coding. I looked over your code and hardly can understand any of it so far, but that is where I am going to start, which is exactly what I was looking for, a place to start. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If you need a hand contact me here or on GitHub and I should be able to help.

Comment: I could use all the help I can get.  First it's on to JSON tuts, and cold beer.